# How do I check if a domain is blacklisted before buying it?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I found a domain which I'm interested in buying from another person (not a registrar or premium domains site) and I am not sure how to find out if it is blacklisted.

I checked http://www.archive.org/ and found nothing. Are there any other sites I should check?

Comment: Are you buying a premium domain or just buying it from a registrar?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I will buy it from a regular person. I am not sure which category this makes it belong to.

Comment: What kind of money are you paying and what is your reason for purchase - traffic, content etc..

Comment: @toomanyairmiles domain name and yes, traffic. I am not sure about the payment approach. for now, I need to be sure that the domain name is healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I'd suggest asking them to add you as a viewer of their google analytics stats so you can learn more about the search performance.

Log out of your google account, delete your cookies and then search google for keywords from their analytics to test their actual search performance.

Look at alexa.com rankings for the domain and check out other domain auction sites to see what similar domains cost.

//update

For blacklists check http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx, http://www.blacklistalert.org/ and http://domain-blacklist.e-dns.org/

You should also attempt to post links to twitter and facebook to ensure that they have not blocked the domain for spamming.

Comment: you misunderstood the question. I am looking for a way to see if the domain is blacklisted or not. Or a similar thing.

Comment: @tugberk that's quite a different question than the one you've asked so I've updated the answer to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this site to see if the domain is blacklisted in Google:

http://onlinealley.com/seotools/googlebannedchecker/

Comment: That last tool is useless. I made up a random domain and it told me it was banned!